# React Tree Org - Persona Id

Tags: reactjs, spfx, persona

what is persona id.why we are using that in react tree org chart in sharepoint.

```
code :  LIVE_PERSONA_COMPONENT_ID: string = '914330ee-2df2-4f6e-a858-30c23a812408';
```

what is persona idwhy we are using that in react tree org chart in share point.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ID of a built-in sharepoint component "LivePersonaCard" (which is not exactly a part of SPFx framework or react or org chart, but of the SharePoint itself). As far as I understand, some people have figured out there is "LivePersonaCard" component and that can be theoretically used from a third-party solution.

I am not quite sure, but it looks like it is neither supported nor documented by Microsoft. I have found these articles referring to the "LivePersonaCard" component. You probably could contact the authors of those to get additional information.

https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-livepersonacard

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52249.sharepoint-online-live-persona-card-in-custom-webpart.aspx